# Ionic Tab Bar More than 4 Elements

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs

I have an application with the `tabs` layout.

I need six `tab-buttons` in the `tab-bar`. There is not enough space for more than 4/5 elements.

So I decided to add an overflow element to the `ion-tab-bar` element. 
But even here the tabs are displayed unfavorably.

**May you have a better solution for me.**

```
    <ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" style="width: 100%; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto;">

    <ion-tab-button tab="registrieren">
      <ion-icon name="person-add"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Registrieren</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="aufnahme">
      <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Aufnahme</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="entfernen">
      <ion-icon name="remove-circle"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Entfernen</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="standortwechsel">
      <ion-icon name="md-car"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Übergabe</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="admin-bestand">
      <ion-icon name="ios-albums"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Bestand</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="system">
      <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>System</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: remove text name and add the only icon or add scroll

Comment: can you add picture your output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
ion-tab-bar {
   overflow-x: scroll;
   justify-content: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do, if you have that many TABS, is to use [ion-segment](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/segment) instead. You can change styles so it can look as a tab, and you can make them slide in horizontal. The examples on ionic docs componets, look ugly but you can make them as TAB. Hope i could help.
 If I'm not mistaken, the BMW's app that connects to the car use ion-segment as tab on the top, and it look preety good.